# "The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed" error, after updating Visual Studio 2012

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have just installed the Update 2 for my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.

After installing the update and restarting the computer, I am not able to build Windows Phone  projects anymore. When I try to build them in VS I always get "The Silverlight 4 SDK is not installed" error.

I have checked, and the SDK is installed. I have also tried by repairing the installation, but nothing. It was working ok befor installing the Visual Studio Update

Does anybody know which is the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have uninstalled and installed again Silverlight 4 SDK with no result. I have checked the Windows Registry, and realized that there is no entry for Silverlight under "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs". Could this be the problem? How do I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by reinstalling the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

I didn't have this problem in my other computer, so I don't know why it happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well when running x64 msbuild. Running the 32-bit version seems to get around the issue.